# trouble with inline and jquery plugins in django

Tags: jquery, django, plugins, django-admin, django-widget

Have troubles with inline in django admin. For example, i want to add a [chosen jquery plugin](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) to my Change_form page.
I'm extends change_from html and add next code

```
{% extends "admin/change_form.html" %}

{% block extrahead %}
{{ block.super }}

<script src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}js/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ MEDIA_URL }}js/chosen.css" type="text/css" />
<style type="text/css">
.form-row {
    overflow: visible;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $("select").chosen();
});
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

All works perfectly, except "selects" in inline when i push "Add more". They work incorrectly. One gets the impression that the plugin works before widget creation, after clicking "Add more".
Same trouble have with [Redactor plugin](http://imperavi.com/redactor/)

[image]
[image: Redactor error]

Answer (score 0):

1) you do not need to change the template to add your own plugin to admin page. Check [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/media/#assets-as-a-static-definition) out. All you need to do is to add your media to your form and add your form to admin page - like it teaches in the page that speaks about django admin.

2) The issue you see is not django, but jquery/javascript issue. If new elements get added to the page then the new elements do not have the event bound to them. I havent used jquery for a while but there used to be "live" method for binding events to elements that get created on the run.

```
$('#element').live('eventname', callback(){});
```